# Ошибка: TypeError: insertion_sort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'А'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Помогите решить проблему, не знаю с чем связана ошибка

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def re():
    N = entry1.get()
    A = [x + 1 for x in range(int(N))]
    random.seed(time.time())
    random.shuffle(A)
    lbl_list["text"] = f"{A}"

def insertion_sort(А): # сортировка вставкой
    # Сортировку начинаем со второго элемента, т.к. считается, что первый элемент уже отсортирован
    for i in range(1, len(А)):
        item_to_insert = А[i]
        # Сохраняем ссылку на индекс предыдущего элемента
        j = i - 1
        # Элементы отсортированного сегмента перемещаем вперёд, если они больше
        # элемента для вставки
        while j >= 0 and А[j] > item_to_insert:
            А[j + 1] = А[j]
            j -= 1
        # Вставляем элемент
        А[j + 1] = item_to_insert
    lbl_result['text'] = f"{item_to_insert}"

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.title('Внутреняя сортировка')

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)


fr_buttons = tk.Frame(root)
btn_gr = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Сгенерировать таблицу", command=re)
btn_is = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Сортировка вставкой", command=insertion_sort)
btn_ss = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Сортировка выборкой")
btn_bs = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Пузырьковая сортировка")

lbl_list = tk.Label(master=root, text="Исходнные данные:")
lbl_result = tk.Label(master=root, text="Отсортированно")
lbl_list.grid(row=2, column=1)
lbl_result.grid(row=3, column=1)
btn_gr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
btn_is.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5)
btn_ss.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
btn_bs.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5)
fr_buttons.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")


root.mainloop()
```

Выдает вот это: ( и честно я не знаю, что с этим делать)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: insertion_sort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'А'
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция `insertion_sort` у вас описана так:

```
def insertion_sort(А):
```

Значит, при её вызове требуется передать ей параметр, а при таком вызове `command=insertion_sort` вызов функции происходит без параметра.

Вам нужно определиться - где вы хотите хранить данные, с которыми работают ваши функции. Возможно, на первом этапе вам нужно просто сделать переменную `A` глобальной и описать обе функции без параметров:

```
def re():
    global A
    N = entry1.get()
    A = [x + 1 for x in range(int(N))]
    ...

def insertion_sort(): # сортировка вставкой
    global A
    ...
```

Тогда у вас значение `A` будет везде одинаково доступно и его не надо будет передавать в параметрах функции. Хотя обычно использование `global` - не очень хороший стиль, но для начала можете попробовать сделать так.